# Problem with dropdown navigation use (Bootstrap)

Tags: angular, navbar, dropdown

I am trying to make some examples in order to improve my skills with this kind of technologies.
When I try to create a new navigation bar using a simple example from **w3schools**: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp
I can see how it's works properly. But when I try to add to my app, the same code, it appears like that:
[navbar example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0QKb.pngIt)
The code, is exactly the same than in the example, but in my local project it is not working!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

It seems that it's happens the same with a button dropdown:
[dropdown button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIwNl.png)

I've tried Chrome, Firefox & Safari. None of them works.
Why it's happens? What am I doing wrong? I have *Bootstrap 4.4.1* installed in my **Angular project**.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show us your code.

Comment: The code is added in the question now! Thanks!

Comment: Have you applied any custom css. I copy pasted your code in a code pen and it works.

Comment: Yes, could be, but I have no idea of how could I know which custom css is. I've tried to start a new project but the same error happens. So it's something I have installed in my computer, instead of in my project?